# Illegal format conversion error displayed cant locate the error? book program

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create a program in which users can input information regarding a book and get a an output back however the code doesn't seem to work. I am getting the Error that is there down below. I am new programming so don't know what is wrong with the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
at C3519369.main(C3519369.java:47)
```

This is the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class books{

public static void main (String[] args) {

    final int MAX_BOOKS = 1;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] title = new String [MAX_BOOKS];
    String[] author = new String [MAX_BOOKS];
    double[] price = new double [MAX_BOOKS];
    String[] publisher = new String [MAX_BOOKS];
    String[] isbn = new String [MAX_BOOKS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BOOKS; i ++) {




        System.out.print("Enter the Title: ");
        title [i] = scan.nextLine ();
        System.out.print("Enter the Author:         ");
        author [i] = scan.nextLine ();
        System.out.print("Enter the Price:        ");
        price [i] = scan.nextDouble ();
        System.out.print("Enter the Publisher:        ");
        publisher [i] = scan.nextLine ();
        System.out.print("Enter the ISBN:        ");
        isbn [i] = scan.nextLine ();
        scan.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println (String.format(("%-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s"), "Title", "Author", "Price", "Publisher"));
    System.out.println (String.format(("%-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s"), "=====", "=====", "=====", "========="));

    final String PRETTY_PRINT = "%-20s %-10s %-10s %6.2f";

    double totalPrice = 0.0;

    for (int i =0; i < MAX_BOOKS; i ++) {

        totalPrice += price [i];

        System.out.println(String.format (PRETTY_PRINT, title [i], author [i], price [i], publisher [i], isbn [i]));
    }

    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Total Price: " + String.format ("%6.2f", totalPrice));
    System.out.println ("Average Price: " + String.format ("%6.2f", totalPrice / MAX_BOOKS));

    scan.close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot format strings as numbers with String.format. `f` refers to a floating point number in String.format, but you are passing a string into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
//PRETTY_PRINT = "%-20s %-10s %-10s %6.2f";
System.out.println(String.format (PRETTY_PRINT, title [i], author [i], price [i], publisher [i], isbn [i]));
```

The string format does not match the given args : `%6.2f` should be used to display a `float` but you give it a `String` (`isbn` is a `String[]`).

You can reproduce the error like this :

```
//Try to replace "yolo" with a float.
System.out.println(String.format("%6.2f", "yolo"));
```